# How to add class to an hyperlink using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I would like to add an additional class to a hyperlink within a span element. I can able to add a div to a combination of span elements using jquery `$( ".q-button" ).wrapAll( "<div class='q-button-wrap' />");`

But I need to set a class to the hyperlink with in the span elements using jquery and also wrap with a new class(like the example at the end of the post).

Here is the php code:

```
function custom_content_filter_the_content( $content ) {
    if ( function_exists('get_field') ) {
      $content .= '<span class="q-button" id="q-button-1" data-icon="a">' . get_field("website") . '</span>';
      $content .= '<span class="q-button" id="q-button-2" data-icon="a">' . get_field("website2") . '</span>';

    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'custom_content_filter_the_content' );
```

The HTML of the content looks exactly like this:

```
<div class="q-button-wrap">
    <span class="q-button" data-icon="a">
        <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
    </span>
    <span class="q-button" data-icon="a">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://http://localhost.site.com/mypost">My post</a>
    </span>
    <span class="q-button" data-icon="a"></span>
</div>
```

The hyper link is inside the `<span class="q-button">` I don't know a proper way to add class to the hyperlink similar to this:

`$( ".q-button" ).wrapAll( "<div class='q-button-wrap' />");`

Could anyone suggest me a solution for this?

Update: 
Also, I want to achieve two things here. 1) I want to add class to the hyper link  2) I need another div wrapping around the hyperlink.

So that should looks like this:

```
<div class="q-button-wrap">
    <span class="q-button" data-icon="a">
        <i class="new-list-class">
            <a href="http://google.com" class="new-class-for-link">Google</a>
        </i>
    </span>
    <span class="q-button" data-icon="a">
        <i class="new-list-class">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://http://localhost.site.com/mypost"  class="new-class-for-link">My post</a>
        </i>
    </span>
    <i class="new-list-class">
        <span class="q-button" data-icon="a"  class="new-class-for-link"></span>
    </i>
</div>
```

Update:

Here is what I tried:

First-time:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$( ".q-button" ).wrapAll( "<div class='q-button-wrap' />"); //to wrap all the elements in the div - This is success but not the other two
$( ".q-button a" ).wrapAll( "<span class='new-link-class-wrap' />"); //wrap the hyperlink
$( ".q-button a" ).addClass('new-class-for-link'); // add class to the link
});
</script>
```

Second-time(as per-[jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$( ".q-button" ).wrapAll( "<div class='q-button-wrap' />"); //  to wrap all the elements in the div-  This is success but not the other two
$( ".q-button a" ).wrapAll( "<span class='new-link-class-wrap' />"); //wrap the hyperlink
$( ".q-button a" ).addClass("new-class-for-link"); // add class to the link
});
</script>
```

I had no luck with any of those two attempts. Failed to achieve the both- add class to the hyperlink and wrap a new class around the hyperlink.

Comment: Not quite sure want you want to achieve but maybe you look for: `$( ".q-button" ).find('a').addClass('yourClass');` ? Is that what you need? Or do you need a soution on the PHP side?

Comment: add a class based on what criteria? Have you looked at `jQuery addClass()`?  What hyperlink, there are none shown? Really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You can always add it on jsfiddle, so it would be easier to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( ".q-button" ).wrapAll( "<div class='q-button-wrap' />");
$( ".q-button a" ).addClass('your-class-here');
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion(tried as shown in the edited question description). I had no luck adding the new class to the hyperlink.

Comment: The code should work. Are you sure that when the document is ready, when this code is called `$( ".q-button a" ).addClass('your-class-here');`, 'a' element is already there? Where do your 'a' elements come from? Are they created dynamically by other javascript function?

Comment: I made a mistake in my jquery file. I fixed it later and your suggestion helped me achieve what I expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CfF2Y/). May be you are not importing the necessary jquery file in your html template. Or there might be some error in your js functions. Check the firebug console for any errors and try to solve it. Hope this helps.

```
$('.q-button a').addClass('myClass');
```